# How to use "LIKE" function on "FROM" clause in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, django

I am trying to query a specific table based on a user input, and want to query the table that contains that user input as the search_id in the name. For example, the table names are structured as `run_000000_search_000000_lda_000000` and I want to get the table that has the same search_id as the on they put in.

I know when "LIKE" is used on the Where clause you can get a column with a specific string or int in the name. However, I have found nothing on using it with the "FROM" clause.

Specific hardcoded query for search_id 50

```
SELECT *
FROM `run_000044_search_000050_lda_000366`;
```

In summary, how can I get the table that has the same search_id as the one the user put in. Also trying to use the run and lda to form a full table name does not work because there is no noticeable pattern in between the 3 names.

I also can use dynamic sql but am not sure how to do it.

Comment: This requires dynamic SQL.  You need to construct the query string you want -- with the right table name -- and pass it into the database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Yes but I do not know the full table name, It is based on the user input. I only know the number after the search ID. I have no idea what the run ID and lda ID are for a specific search ID unless I hardcode all 6000 of them

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have dynamic SQL but I do not know the full string name, so would it still be possible?

Comment: This question seams to be related to bad design choices.. As using metadata to separate table names is generally not a really a good approach most likely done because you think it will be faster..  Best is to use one single table as MySQL can handle millions even numbers in the billion(s) of records just fine when indexed..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I did not create the table or the database, it is computer generated from running tests and collecting data, Is there no way to directly use a like clause in the from statement?

Comment: *"I did not create the table or the database, it is computer generated from running tests and collecting data"* Even if that is the case just load everything in one single table after... Simply use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... ` it will make your live alot more easy.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Would this not take too long with the amount of tables and columns I have? Also some information is stored within the table name themselves, is there anyway to keep this data? For example, the specific search_ID is located in the name, because there are multiple instances of the same WHERE clause within different tables, that would give me the wrong data.

Comment: your current number of tables are most likely already slowing down the MySQL server as databases/table are implemented as dirs/files.. if you have already have thousands of tables your OS wil most likely already slow down opening a table.. As thousands as files in one dir is not good for performance...

Comment: @RaymondNijland The database is external so I have not downloaded this onto my computer. At least that is what I understand from the pages I have read online.

Comment: *"The database is external so I have not downloaded this onto my computer. At least that is what I understand from the pages I have read online."* Pretty sure you do not understand what i meant there..  -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-mapping.html and https://serverfault.com/questions/98235/how-many-files-in-a-directory-is-too-many-downloading-data-from-net

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have found the answer I wanted and added it as an answer. I just wanted to know whether or not it was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching online I have finally found out a solution. The infomation_schema.tables contains a column will a table names. From here you can query the full name of the table and use that in another query. I think that a full example makes it much easier to understand:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_search_000050_lda_%';
```

```
SELECT * FROM INFROMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

^ selects table will containing all table names and

```
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_search_000050_lda_%';
```

^ search all tables for whats in the quotes. Replace the '%_seach_000050_lda_%' with the Like statement you need for the table

Comment: Be very careful when constructing these kinds of queries with user input. There are lots and lots of ways this could go very wrong if any part of your stack's security isn't tight.

Comment: @FlipperPA Yes this query is vulnerable to SQL injections but in my case I do not have to worry because this is a private website that will be used by only a few users

Answer (score 0):

LIKE is usually used in WHERE clause after FROM for example

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE field LIKE 'value';
```

you can also compare number or int field by '=' operator which return a specific record.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = 30;
```

if you want extract details from specific record set of another table you can subquery method for example refer this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-sub-queries-clause/)

you can also use dynamic sql query.refer this [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/) for dynamic sql query

Comment: I want to query a column with a specific ID number from a table that contains my search ID in it. So basically, there is no way to use Like on the table names unless I use a subquery. I am currently using dynamic sql queries so is there anyway to do it using dynamic queries?

Comment: you can define field execute query in this [link](https://data-flair.training/blogs/dynamic-sql/) you see an examples of dynamic sql queries

Comment: I am still new to SQL and do not really understand how to do this in my situation. Can you give me an example of how to do it?